# Reverse look up a Sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I recently started working at a company, and am trying to figure out how a certain SharePoint app was created (trying to look up its workflow and form design).

I tried accessing it through SharePoint Designer, but had no success. I can't see any settings, and when I click on Workflows, it says there are no workflows, even though I'm positive that there should be since an email gets sent in the process.

I'm using Office 365 SharePoint; the list is a Tasks list created on a Team site.

Comment: Check the alerts for the list. Might be from there the mails are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the task list settings and check the advanced settings. The option to email on assignment is probably enabled. If it is not enabled and there are no workflows on the list, then it has to be an alert configured.

It should be pretty apparent if it is an alert email versus an assignment email, they are drastically different.

Comment: It's an assignment email that based on the department chosen, an email goes out.
Also, is it possible to look up how the app was designed if it wasn't using InfoPath?

Comment: Then I'm assuming the Assigned To column is set to choose from SharePoint groups, which then in turn emails all the members of the group on assignment.